# JQuery AJAX response which includes jQuery code

Tags: jquery, ajax, response

I have an application which using dynamic page loading. Everything works fine, but I need to use special javascript code for some specific sections. So it's useless include these js files into the header. So my response contains some html code and  js include

I declared for example action for "click" event (toggling image of checkbox) on my application section "todo", when I opened this section and clicked on element which have defined click event, checkbox successfully toggling the image. But when I loaded another section and return back to this "todo" section, after the same click toggling function run twice. When I repeat this process again, toggling function run three times.

Can somebody help me how to avoid this?

Sorry, here's example of my click event code:

```
    $('#container').on('click','.todo-list .todo-done',function(){
    var state = '';
    if(currentTODO.find('.todo-done').hasClass('fa-square')) {
        state = 0;
    } else {
        state = 1;
    }
    //return false;
    $.post(todoUrl + 'index/toggle_active/',{'id':currentTODO.data('id'), 'state':state},function(){
        if(currentTODO.find('.todo-done').hasClass('fa-check-square')) {
            currentTODO.removeClass('done');
            currentTODO.find('.todo-done').removeClass('fa-check-square').addClass('fa-square');
        } else {
            currentTODO.addClass('done');
            currentTODO.find('.todo-done').removeClass('fa-square').addClass('fa-check-square');
        }            
    });
});
```

And there's example of my response:

```
<div class="content"> 
<script src="todo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <i class="fa fa-check-square todo-done"></i>
        <div class="text">
            <div class="text-text">TODO item</div>
            <div class="link">
                <div class="link-text"><a href="" target="_blank"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add code example.

Comment: If you provide what code you have and what your ajax response is we can probably help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use unbind function before declaration of 'click' event. More here: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/